# Error in printing output when using fscanf in C

Tags: c, file-handling

Here's a code I have been working on C.

```
char Host_ip[256];
char *Database_name;
char *Username;
int listen_port;

FILE *myfile = fopen("Coin_Converter.config", "r");
fscanf(myfile, "Host=%s Database=%s Username=%s listenport=%d", Host_ip, Database_name,
                                                Username, &listen_port);
fclose(myfile);

printf("Host = %s", Host_ip);
printf("Username= %s", Username);
printf("Database= %s", Database_name);
printf("listenport = %d", listen_port);
```

My config file looks like this:

```
Host = 127.0.0.1
Database = base20
Username = John
listenport = 8080
```

I don't have any issue with compiling the code but I am not able to print anything. Infact, when I only print Host_ip it's working but otherwise I am not getting anything.
I tried few things but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Database_name and Username are not initialized.

Comment: *Always* check the value returned by scanf.  In this case, if `fscanf` does not return 4, then you are invoking undefined behavior by printing uninitialized values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main mistakes in your code are

- Using unallocated pointers instead of buffers
- Not filtering whitespace from the input stream.

With some changes (commented) the code becomes

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char Host_ip[256];
    char Database_name[256];        // array instead of pointer
    char Username[256];             // array instead of pointer
    int listen_port;

    FILE *myfile = fopen("Coin_Converter.txt", "r");
    if(myfile == NULL)
        return 1;
    fscanf(myfile, "Host = %255s Database = %255s Username = %255s listenport = %d",
                Host_ip, Database_name, Username, &listen_port);    // added spaces
    fclose(myfile);

    printf("Host = %s\n", Host_ip);             // added newlines
    printf("Username= %s\n", Username);
    printf("Database= %s\n", Database_name);
    printf("listenport = %d\n", listen_port);
}
```

and outputs

```
Host = 127.0.0.1
Username= John
Database= base20
listenport = 8080
```

The added spaces in the `fscanf` format string are to remove any whitespace (or none) from the input stream.

Comment: It's working. Thanks a lot.